# Property [products] does not exist on this collection instance. (View:

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to get products related to that category from index page but at product listing page it shows error,

controller:

```
 public function products(Request $request, Product $product)
 {
     $categories = Category::distinct()->get();
     return view('product.listing', compact('product', 'categories'));
 }
```

blade file:

```
   @foreach($categories->products as $product)

     <div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
      <a href="product-detail.html" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5">

       {{ $product->product_name }
     </a>

<span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5">            
        $75.00
    </span>
    </div>

  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that you are missing the relationship in your `Category` model. You should have something like this:

```
class Category ... {

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Now for this to work in your `products` table you should have a `category_id` column for each product.

The problem is that this returns a collection `$categories = Category::distinct()->get();`

So you need to loop twice:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

  // then here
  @foreach ($category->products as $product)
...
```

Comment: I also have it in model:::: public function products()
    {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

Answer (score 1):

You need relationship between category and product model like this:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Now, Use eager loading.

```
 public function products(Request $request, Product $product)
 {
     $categories = Category::with('products')->distinct()->get();
     return view('product.listing', compact('product', 'categories'));
 }
```

After this you can access products in view as `$category->products`

Comment: @dev I have added complete controller code, have a try

Comment: @dev As nakov mentioned in another answer, you need to loop twice. Sice categories is collection of category and products is like property of individual category.